# How to disable product image thumbnails for woocommerce gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I work on slider for woocommerce product gallery and I don't use/need the generated thumbnails, because I use "dots" for navigation and I want to hide/unload the generated thumbnails by woocommerce gallery.

Firstly, I put this in my theme **functions.php** file :

```
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

And actually, I just put **"display:none"** in my css file and I make this for the **product-thumbnails.php** :

```
// Note: `wc_get_gallery_image_html` was added in WC 3.3.2 and did not exist prior. This check protects against theme overrides being used on older versions of WC.
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
    return;
}

global $post, $product;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

if ( $attachment_ids && $product->get_image_id() ) { ?>

<div class="slider product-responsive-thumbnail" id="product_thumbnail_<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>">
    <?php foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) { ?>
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id ), $attachment_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    } ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I would like to disable the generation of thumbnails and its display completely to optimize the loading of my page!

I know that I can totally delete the contents of the file **"produtc-thumbnails.php"** but it is a bit raw method and I would like to know if this is possible with another less raw method

Comment: There are several ways for this, as you have already indicated yourself. 
For example, you can convert the code you don't want to use to comment (by comment tags) or just replace `$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();` with `$attachment_ids = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@7uc1f3r** suggested to me,

First simple solution. Mask in the **woocommerce-general.css** file like this:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs {
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    display:none; /* this hide the thumbnails */
}
```

Second solution, put "**false**" in the **product-thumbnails.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
    return;
}

global $post, $product;

$attachment_ids = false; // This disable the thumbnails
```

And voilà, now it's up to you to choose the method you want to keep.